# Using CASE to update a field

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, sqlserver

I'm getting an error on my case statement in SFMC. Is it a simple mistake of syntax?

```
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN status <> 'active' THEN 'active' ELSE status END AS status
FROM [sample table]
WHERE status <> 'active'
```

The query's goal is simply to change any non-active status (in this specific data extension) to 'active.' It'll actually be based on a date field, but for now I'm simply having an issue with the case statement.

**Error**

> An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: The column 'status' was specified multiple times for 'Qry'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you already have status by select * (status was already present  in the table). I would advise you either don't use the select * or change the alias of the case function e.g. Substatus.

If you target de has a primary key, we could speed this alot by Setting the Write Mode to Update and doing this:

```
SELECT
WhichEverColumnIsYourPrimaryKey
,'active' AS status
FROM [sample table]
WHERE status <> 'active'
```

If your target DE doesnt have a primary key, you could still speed things up by not using the "CASE" function. Reasoning behind this is that `WHERE status <> 'active'` is already filtering out all status that are not active. You could just do this.

```
SELECT

Column1
,Column2
,Column3
,ColumnN
,'active' AS status
FROM [sample table]
WHERE status <> 'active'
```

Hope this helps.